# How to find a set of events which are not independent pairwise but independent jointly?

Tags: probability

> Four fair coins are tossed. Find three events $A$, $B$ and $C$ which are not pairwise independent but mutually independent.

Is there any particular method to solve these kinds of questions?

Comment: What is your defintion of jointly independent? According to the usual definition any subcollection of jointly independent events is independent.

Comment: Are you sure the problem didn't say "pairwise independent but not mutually independent"?

Comment: If three events are mutually independent then they are pairwise independent.

Answer (score 2):

If you want pairwise independent events which are not jointly independent here is my answer. (The way you have stated, the question is wrong).

In two independent tosses of fair coin consider the following events:

a) the two outcomes are the same (both heads or both tails)

b) the first toss results in Heads

c) the second toss results in Heads

You can verify that these are pairwise independent but not jointly independent.